# How to fix "callee return nil (error type), but caller check that err != nil is still true"

Tags: go

```
var engine *xorm.Engine

func DbFunc(ctx context.Context) (err error) {
   user := UserTab{UserId: 1}
   err = engine.Context(ctx).Table("user_tab").InsertOne(user)
   if IsMySQLDuplicatedError(err) {
     return err
   }
   return nil
}

if err = DbFunc(ctx); err != nil {
  err.Error() // <- panic: nil pointer reference
}
```

Turns out the root cause is that even though `err != nil` is true, `err` itself is actual nil error, which is mind boggling

I found this FAQ that might be related (https://go.dev/doc/faq#nil_error), but I still can't figure out how to fix this

Comment: The problem is in DoSomething().  The FAQ shows how to fix the problem.

Comment: > The problem is in DoSomething()

it is actually just xorm library call, outside of my control

I expanded the example code

Comment: This is probably a bug in xorm. It is returning a typed-error with nil value. The type is apparently a MYSQLDuplicatedError type. This probably happens because somewhere a MySQLDuplicateError is declared as nil, and returned. The fix would be to check where it was returned to see if it is nil, and return a nil error. A nil MySQLDuplicatedError is not a nil error.

Comment: Check out this [minium example](https://go.dev/play/p/sXBNmdhuw2o)

Comment: please add the code for `IsMySQLDuplicatedError`. according to your snippet, this is the only condition under which a non nil error can be returned, correct ?

Comment: can you also paste the stack trace of your "nil pointer dereference" ? it may be a bug in the implementation of the `Error()` method, rather than just a "non nil interface to a nil value" bug -- for example: if the `Error() string` method of `xorm.WhateverError` type accesses `e.inner.Error()` without checking if `e.inner` is not nil.